# Sending Attachments Amazon SES API vs. SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, email, amazon-web-services

In looking at amazon's SES API documentation it looks as if there is no clear cut way for sending attachments unless a raw email is created.  Where as when using an SMTP Client to amazons SES sending emails with attachments seems more manageable.  Outside of the messageid returned from the SES API is there any benefit to using the api over the SMTP client?  Or am I completely missing the boat and there is an easy implementation of adding attachments to an email in the SES API?

Answer (score 1):

I use SES all the time, have never felt a need to use anything other than the SMTP interface - which is a simple drop-in replacement for any other SMTP service you may be using. Unless you have a compelling reason (and I can't think of any), use the regular old SMTP way. Then if you ever need to move off, it would be trivial to switch to another service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main reason to use the api is you can set a domain key to improve delivery success rate. This is useful if you send a huge amount of emails. In general, unless you have an easy way to implement the api (like django-ses or similar) just stick with SMTP.

Comment: I think domain verification can also be configured by the AWS console, meaning that it can be used with SMTP access.